# Filter input amount at specific points in regex?

Tags: regex, go

How would someone do something like this in regex...

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,254}+@$
```

Comment: Elaborate on `something like this`

Comment: I am tempted to downvote the question, as it contains no usable information and its (to me) unclear what the question is. But I'll apply a new user's bonus :)

Comment: That is the reason why I didn't downvote it. But appalled to see OP had time to comment on an answer below but doesn't care about clarifying the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[A-Za-z0-9]{1,254}` Indicates ,

any character of: `'A' to 'Z'`, `'a' to 'z'`,
                           `'0' to '9'`

(between 1 and 254 times
                           (matching the most amount possible)),

[image]

**Edit:** If you need `@` at the end try with the regex `[A-Za-z0-9]{1,254}@`

Comment: True, but if I I enter

abcdef@ it is false.